# Can I access the in-game console in The Witcher 3 on PS4?

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

Is there any way to access the in-game console in *The Witcher 3* on PS4 to type custom commands? If yes, how can I access it?

Comment: Console versions don't have in-game consoles for many reasons. It's a security hole. It un-levels the playing field especially in multiplayer. The preconditions for getting a game certified by the console maker prohibit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this source](http://www.mmo-game.eu/witcher-3-debug-console-commands/), the console is not natively available even on the PC version of the game. A separate mod, hosted on the Nexus website, is needed to access the in-game console. And, since the console version of Witcher 3 does not support mods, the in-game console cannot be accessed.

Comment: Good, I didn't know it wasn't even available on PC. Great, thanks!